# Using two different header in one theme

Tags: php

How can I change the header part of a design with a button? I want all css and images to change. What terms should I research? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: can you share more details theme wordpress , html ,php then i can be do some thing for you .

Comment: I am thinking of using whmcs for automation. Theme engine smarty. I want to understand the logic through PHP examples.

Comment: you have to create two files of header then on button set session off that header and then you can add if($_SESSION['header1']){ include('header1.php');}else{ include('header2.php');}  i hope you got your answer .

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm starting the experiment :) Have you found any videos on this topic?